# PHP: Trying to understand subpattern regex match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to understand how subpatterns work and I am a little confused about something:

```
$var2 = 'cat dog cow moose bat';
$match = preg_match(
    "/(dog)/",
    $var2,
    $arr
);
var_dump($arr);
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "dog" [1]=> string(3) "dog" }
```

I'm not sure why there are 2 elements in the array. Reading my php book (quote from book blow) I'm assuming the 0th element in the array is the match of the entire string while the second element is the match of just the substring. Is this correct? Just want to make sure I understand this.

"The zeroth element of the array is set to the entire string being matched against. The
first element is the substring that matched the first subpattern (if there is one), the
second element is the substring that matched the second subpattern, and so on."

Comment: Yes you are correct, in your case you just have 1 element so match[0] = match[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract from [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) documentation :

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Then, with `/(dog)/` regex, you'll have :

- `$matches[0]` containing `/(dog)/` results (full pattern)
- `$matches[1]` containing `(dog)` results (first capturing group)

If your first capturing group is equal to you full pattern, then `match[0] = match[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Its correct ....

- [0] = matched full pattern - ie dog
- [1] = first captured - ie dog

since your **whole** pattern is also captured (`()`) then both will be the same.

If you used the regex `/cat (dog)/` the results would be

- [0] = matched full pattern - ie cat dog
- [1] = first captured - ie dog